# Find all positive integer $m$ such $2^{m}+1\mid5^m-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, diophantine-equations

> Find all positive integer $m$ such
>   $$2^{m}+1\mid5^m-1\,.$$

It seem there no solution, I think it might be necessary to use quadratic reciprocity  knowledge to solve this problem.

Let $M=2^m+1$, so we have
$$5^{m}\equiv 1\pmod{M}. $$
If $m$ is odd, then we have
$$\left(5^{\frac{m+1}{2}}\right)^2=5\pmod {M}\Longrightarrow \left(\dfrac{5}{M}\right)=1,$$
so
$$\left(\dfrac{M}{5}\right)(-1)^{\frac{(5-1)(M-1)}{4}}=\left(\dfrac{M}{5}\right)(-1)^M=-\left(\dfrac{M}{5}\right).$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @RobertZ  I have post my some try,Following step I can't do it

Comment: Are we assuming $(2^m+1)\mid(5^m-1)$?

Comment: @manooooh,yes. it's right

Comment: If $m$ is odd then $2^m +1$ is divisible by 3 but $5^m - 1$ is not. No need for quadratic reciprocity

Comment: After doing mod $3$ like @user420261 suggested, expanding $5^m=(4+1)^m$ gives that $4\mid 5^m-1$, hence $12\mid 5^m-1$.

Comment: Also note that $M = 2^m + 1$ is not necessarily prime so you cannot apply quadratic reciprocity without further justification. For example $49 = 7^2$ is a perfect square $\pmod 5$, but $5$ is not a perfect square $\pmod {49}$. In other words, it is not true in general that $\left(\frac{p^2}{5}\right) = \left(\frac{5}{p^2}\right)$ for odd prime $p \neq 5$ even though a blind application of QR would suggest that.

Comment: Copy of the question on MathOverflow: [Find all $m$ such $2^m+1\mid5^m-1$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/317643). It think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) provides a very reasonable advice on [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Comment: For $m=5$ , $2^m+1=33=3\times 11$ and $5^m-1=4\times 11\times 71$, that is they have a common divisor 11. I dont think we can go farther. They just may have common divisors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been asked and answered by the same user on MathOverflow.